# I need to Undo my Redirection URL done by Redirection Plugin

Tags: wordpress, localhost, redirect, http-redirect

I have used the REDIRECTION plugin and redirected the URL http://localhost/word/wordpress/product-category/sample/ to http://localhost/word/wordpress/sample/. The first thing it redirects all my product category page to destination URL. So, I need to undo this. But I couldn't find a solution for these. Kindly Suggest me some ideas.

I had tried to remove the redirects line from .htaccess, but nothing happened.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /word/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /word/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

If I remove the redirect lines, it displays like,

> Object not found!
>        The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the 
>        referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author 
>        of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
>
> Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.1.20

Answer (score 0):

You can just deactivate the REDIRECTION plugin, which you are using it will work as like earlier.

Comment: ... or go to the Redirection plugin settings page and remove said redirection rule.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

The redirect lines in .htaccess are not added by redirection plugin. Those lines are added by Wordpress permalink to work. You are using the postname slug in the permalink url of wordpress. So, if you remove those lines from .htaccess, the permalink stops working and you are getting this error.

For the incorrect redirection, you only need to remove the redirection rule from the redirection plugin settings page or you can disable the plugin.